# Access Button Name that called a common dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Application in which  the MainWindow.xaml has two buttons that call a common dialog box on click. Here's the code snippet:

```
<Button Name="Button1" Content="Save 1" Click="Button1_Click"/>
<Button Name="Button2" Content="Save 2" Click="Button2_Click"/>
```

Button1_Click and Button2_Click invoke SaveDialog.xaml on click. There is a button in this dialog called OK:

```
<Button Name="OKBtn" Content="OK" Click="OKBtn_Click"/>
```

The snippet from SaveDialog.xaml.cs is as follows.

```
private void OKBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Access Button Name from Main Window that called this dialog and store it in a string

    }
```

Can someone please help me access the name of the button from the MainWindow that invoked this SaveDialog inside the OK button click event of SaveDialog.xaml.cs. I tried and tried but never got the solution. It is essential for me to get the name of the button. Combining the save buttons is out of the question as they have different functionality but they call the same dialog box.

Comment: You need to add a property to SaveDialog.xaml.cs which you use to indicate which button was used to show this dialog.

Comment: can you share why do you want save button name in OKBtn_Click? there will be better way of achieving what you want to do

Comment: Dear nit, Based on the button name, SaveDialog will have to save some files in different locations. I am not allowed to have separate dialogs for this. I tried passing the location from the MainWindow to this dialog unsuccessfully. That's why I want to store the path locations in SaveDialog.xaml.cs and based on button name, save the files into their appropriate locations.

Comment: I have solved the problem myself. Its solution is so simple it never occurred to me. I wrote two functions called getpath() and setpath(string) in SaveDialog.xaml.cs and, Button1_Click and Button2_Click will just set the path by calling setpath and passing the location as an argument.

The OKBtn_CLick() will just use getPath() to get the path name and save the file... There was no need to access the button name after all.. stupid me!

Comment: @user2869663, [please add your solution into an answer and mark it as the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that other users know that this has been answered and can easily find the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to do this is setting an Uid to your buttons, example:

```
<Button Name="Button1" Uid="000" Content="Save 1" Click="Button1_Click"/>
<Button Name="Button2" Uid="111" Content="Save 2" Click="Button2_Click"/>
```

Then on OKBtn_Click event you could do this:

```
private void OKBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = Ctype(sender, Button)
        If(b.Uid = "000") {
           SaveFile;
        }
        Else{
           SaveOtherFile;
         }
    }
```

Comment: This is an excellent and simpler solution indeed! Thank you Alexandre.